# Does the motion of a free electron in a plane wave electromagnetic field have analytical solutions?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, specific-reference, plasma-physics

Does the motion $[x(t), y(t), z(t)]$ of a free electron in plane wave electromagnetic field have analytical solution (oscillating E and B fields)?

The Lorentz force is :

\begin{align}m_e\begin{bmatrix}x''\\y''\\z''\end{bmatrix}
&=
-e\begin{bmatrix}E\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}e^{i\omega t}
-e\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}0\\B\\0\end{bmatrix}e^{i\omega t}
\\ &=
-e\left(
\begin{bmatrix}E\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-z'B\\0\\x'B\end{bmatrix}
\right)e^{i\omega t}
\end{align}

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem?  Are you asking if there is an analytical solution?  Or if there is a *figure-of-eight* solution?

Comment: Yes I have tried the result that mathematica gives is quite complicated. z=(E*(t - int(cos((B*a0*(sin(p + w*x) - sin(p)))/w), x, 0, t)))/B This is from matlab simplification, still not analytical. Its an integral over infinate series of bessel functions.

Comment: In a region of uniform and constant electric and magnetic fields, the solution is analytic if you neglect bremstralung, and it is a helix (or some degenerate limit of a helix).

Comment: Is the figure 8 is a solution to plane wave EM field in certain frame, still oscillating fileds ?

Comment: I would assume you could tune the amplitude and frequency of the plane wave to maintain such a state. It's not clear to me how you would set up the initial conditions to realize it in real life, but on the white-board it should be possible.

Comment: So what you really want to know is how you can get a figure-of-eight motion?

Comment: I see the derivation in landaus book its way too complicated for me :). I just wonder if only in the frame of electron there is analytical solution or the lorentz force can be solved also.